# Microsoft /adminconcent endpoint - Who authorized my app?

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-authentication

I have an Azure client application that uses Microsoft graph APIs.
I am using the workflow described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow to have admin authorize my azure client application for his tenant.

This flow ends up giving my client application an access token which my client can use to access various resources in the tenant.

Now, my client application needs to find out is 'who' provided the concent. The access token I get does not have this information (unlike in case of other authorization flows).

A tenant may have multiple admins and my application needs to know who among those admins authorized my client application.

What is the best way to find this out?

Thanks,
~ Urjit

Answer (score 0):

> my client application needs to find out is 'who' provided the concent.

You want to find the admin that authorize your client app, as I know, there is no way to find out this information about the admin. Because when you consenting permission for your app, you need the admin to do this for your account. After admin consent, there will be no record for this, no matter in token or portal.